Why does an img with a cross-origin source load when a browser loads a web page?
If I create a simple web page with just a body and an image, for example:


<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="image" src=https://knowpathology.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/happy-test-screen.jpg alt="" width="400" height="400">
</body>

</html>



It loads fine even though the src is from a cross-origin (not the original domain that served the page). Is this supposed to happen? I thought that's what the crossorigin attribute was for. I've searched for info and all I can find is explanation telling that cross-origin is disabled by default, then why does this work?

Answered here How we can load images even there is a concept call same origin policy?

@Phil OK, it turns out the answer to that the answer to that question is wrong, according to the comments on it. So what's the real answer?

The information on cross-origin embedding seems accurate to me. See also Cross-origin network access which says the same
